# how to resolve refreshbrokermetadata failed issue in node?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, node-kafka-streams

Getting below issue while integrating kafka with node after certain time of application get started in node server.

There is not any log in kafka server as well as it is up and running.

```
/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5329
            return callback.apply(null, arguments);
                            ^
NestedError: refreshBrokerMetadata failed
    at /app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:378:35
    at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
    at next (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5329:29)
    at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
    at KafkaClient.getAvailableBroker (/app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:330:12)
    at /app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:373:23
    at nextTask (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5324:14)
    at Object.waterfall (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5334:5)
    at KafkaClient.refreshBrokerMetadata (/app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:372:9)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:782:20)
Caused By: Error: Unable to find available brokers to try
    at KafkaClient.getAvailableBroker (/app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:330:21)
    at /app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:373:23
    at nextTask (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5324:14)
    at Object.waterfall (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5334:5)
    at KafkaClient.refreshBrokerMetadata (/app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:372:9)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/app/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:782:20)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```